# Exception: ideviceinfo returned an error: ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -17

Tags: flutter

I tried install flutter on my mac but these error always show up :

```
⢿Unhandled exception:
Exception: ideviceinfo returned an error:
ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -17
```

can anyone help me?

I've tried many ways but the error always show up.

Answer (score 19):

I think it is caused by having an iOS device plugged in to your computer. I had the same issue and it went away after unplugging my phone. You won't get this message if the device is plugged in and the computer is marked as a trusted device.